# Chai's satisfy function is not returning the expected value

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, chai

So I have an object like below and I wanna check both `""` and `String`. I mean the test case should pass whether it is a string literal or a string object.

*The js file*

```js
// * Changing this object to solve the issue is not allowed
const obj = {
  a: {
    format: "url"
  },
  b: {
    format: String
  }
};
```

As you can see `a's` `format` is a string literal while `b's` `format` is an object.

The wired case is I'm curious that what kind of value is coming under `s` parameter (in the test case satisfy). Because it keeps returning `false` for `b's` `format` but `true` for `a's` `format`.

*The mocha test file*

```js
it('`format` should be a string', () => {
  // this returns true
  chai.expect(obj.a.format).to.satisfy(function (s) {
    return (typeof (s) === 'string') || (s instanceof String);
  });
  // sadly this returns false
  chai.expect(obj.b.format).to.satisfy(function (s) {
    return (typeof (s) === 'string') || (s instanceof String);
  });
});
```

*The test output*

```
`format` should be a string:

AssertionError: expected [Function: String] to satisfy [Function]
+ expected - actual

-false
+true
```

What is the issue here? I was hoping that `obj.a.format` should addressed by `typeof(s) === 'string'` while `obj.b.format` addressed by `s instanceof String`? And how do I make the test case to accept both scenarios, whether it is a `"string"` or `String`?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Yes, but the condition `(typeof (s) === 'string') || (s instanceof String)` should be true in both cases, isn't it?

Comment: In which the satisfy function should return true right?

Comment: Most certainly not. A class/prototype is not an _instance_ of itself.

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish my goal in this case?

Comment: are you not looking at the answer I posted?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I actually want the test case to accept both scenarios. Whether it is a `"string"` or `String`.

Comment: If you want something not in your post, update your post. Until then, the answer I've written for you explains what's wrong, and what you can do instead.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Thanks for your answer, which greatly explains what I was thinking to make the condition inside the `satisfy`.

Comment: const obj = {
      a: {
        format: "url"
      },
      b: {
        format: new String('url')
      }
    };

I think this would solve your problem

Comment: @AshishRawat Changing the `obj` is not allowed. :(

Comment: @dinindu Sorry I didn't read the commented line I think you should read how instanceof works for a better understanding.

Comment: @AshishRawat No worries :) Yes, I was wrong, Mike explained it in his answer below, which makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Remember: the type of "string" is string, because it's a string. Nothing weird there. But the type of `String` is object, because it's the String prototype object, and a prototype is by definition not an *instance* of itself, so neither `typeof (s) === 'string'` or `s instanceof String` will be true. So if you want to check if `b` is a  string instance or the actual `String` prototype, use `s === String`, not `s instanceof String`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, which greatly explains what I was thinking to make the condition inside the `satisfy`.